# Let $f$ be continuous at $[-1,3]$ with $f(-1)<-1$ and $f(3)>3$. Use Bolzano's method to prove that $f$ has at least one fixed point in $[-1,3]$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

> Let $f$ be a function that is continuous at $[-1;3]$. It is known that
>   $f(-1) < -1$ and $f(3)>3$.
>
> Use Bolzano's method to prove that $f$ has at least one fixed point at
>   $]-1;3[$.

This problem barely gives me any information, so if I had to take a wild guess at what $f(x)$ looks like I think it would look like this:
$$
f(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             >x  & x > 0 \\
             \\ <x, & x< 0 \\
             \\ 
             \end{array}
   \right.
$$

I also assume that $f(x)$ is part of a family of many functions to which the above definition applies, and so this fixed point is a point that all functions in that family have in common.

So, is this fixed point $0$?

Assuming it is, I can prove that this fixed point is within the given range by using Bolzano's method as follows:

$$f(-1) < -1$$
$$f(3) > 3$$
$$f(0) = 0$$
$$-1 < 0 < 3$$
$$f(-1) < f(0) < f(3)$$

Is this correct? My book doesn't state any solution.

Comment: It's definitely not that case that $f(0)=0$ for all such $f$. The value $c$ where $f(c)=c$ will vary with $f$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Then how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Every continuous function $f:[a,b]\to [a,b]$ has a fixed point , using Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: If I was going to post an answer, I'd have posted an answer. I know how to prove it in some ways, but not with the "method of Bolzano."

Comment: But this is specifically not such a function, @S717717: $f(a)<a$ and $f(b)>b$. Yet it is still true, and again by the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: I don't know what bolzano method is, but the standard method is to show that f(x) - x must equal zero someplace.

Comment: $f(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             >x  & x > 0 \\
             \\ <x, & x< 0 \\
             \\ 
             \end{array}
   \right.$ there is absolutely no reason to assume that.  All you know is $f(-1) < -1$ you could have $f(-1.1) = + 2,317$ and that $f(3) > 3$.  You could have $f(2.9) = -5,398$ and $f(3.1) = 0$.  What you do know is that for $-1 < d < 3$ there is a $-1 < c < 3$ so that $f(c) = d$. But you don't know which if them (if any) are fixed.

Comment: @fleablood Bolzano's method is usually called the "bisection method" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method

Comment: Hmm, I really like your answer, but I think the book is assuming to solve for g(x) = f(x) - x = 0.  But we could modify to BM to go from finding f(a_n) < 0 f(b_n) to solve f(x)=0 to finding f(a_n) < a_n and f(b_n) > b_n to solve for f(x) = x.  That's a very clever answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better consider the function $x \mapsto f(x) - x$ instead. Apply the Bolzano thing to this function. I am almost sure you can complete it from here on.

Comment: How do you know that $x \mapsto f(x) - x$ ? Also, is $\mapsto$ the same as $\rightarrow$?

Comment: That is defining a second function:  g(x) = f(x) -x.  g is also continuous.  g(x) = 0 if and only if f(x) = x.   It's not a statement.  It's a definition.

Comment: I think I got it. If $f(c) -c = 0$ and $h(x) = f(x) -x$, then $h(-1) < h(0) < h(3)$. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the Bolzano's method proof is to take $a_0=-1,b_0=3$ and at step $n$ define $c_n=\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}$.

If $f(c_n)=c_n$ we are done.

Otherwise, if $f(c_n)<c_n$ then define $a_{n+1}=c_n,b_{n+1}=b_n$. If $f(c_n)>c_n$ then define $a_{n+1}=a_n,b_{n+1}=c_n$.

So we are picking the "half" interval $[a_{n+1},b_{n+1}]$ from the previous interval  $[a_n,b_n]$ such that $f(a_{n+1})<a_{n+1}$ and $f(b_{n+1})>b_{n+1}$.

Now, apply the Bolzano method to these decreasing intervals, we have that $a_{n}$ and $b_n$ converge to the same value $c$. Since $f(b_n)>b_n$ for all $n$ we have $f(c)\geq c$ and similarly since $f(a_n)<a_n$ for all $n$, we have that $f(c)\leq c$.

Comment: Why is $c_n=\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}$?

Comment: Because you are splitting the previous interval $[a_n,b_n]$ in half. @MarkRead - $[a_n,c_n]$ being one half and $[c_n,b_n]$ the other.